# Mathml Rendering Library Other than MathJax: Android

Tags: android, performance, math, webview, mathml

I am using MathJax in my application to render Mathml in WebViews.
I see that this library MathJax is very slow in rendering Mathml.

**Is There any other library that can be used to Render Mathml.**
Please help, by your inputs as Suggestion in comments or links to repository.

Thanks in Advance,
Jose

Comment: Yes, try KaTeX from Khan Academy.  It performs very well in benchmarks: https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX

Comment: @duffymo i did ask the developer of the Khan Academy they replied "Its not Android Specific Library" here's the link to the issue https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/issues/194

Comment: It's JavaScript; I don't know what Android specific has to do with it: "There's no special support for Android in particular."

Comment: Yes Thats what i said @duffymo have you ever tried this lib for Android or can you give me some idea about how to go with this.

Comment: I haven't tried it for Android.  I assumed it would either run in a browser or be parsed in a JavaScript engine like Rhino.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Android, you can use [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox), by developing a Webapp, that has native MathML support and because of it will be much faster than MathJax or other Javascript solution. The only "problem" right know is that Android don't have fonts that support math and because of it the render can be not as good as you want.